# I have two buttons in a row, both containing icons, but if one of the icons is larger, the other button gets pushed down despite same height. Why?

Tags: javascript, html, css, stenciljs

I am using Web Components on Stencil.js. I have an icon component, and a button component. I have nested the icon component inside the button component, but I have noticed that, when I have two buttons aligned next to each other, and one of them has an icon a bit larger than the other one, the other button gets pushed down. This is to be expected if the line-height is larger, but in my case, I don't think that it is.

Button:

```
<button >
   {this.icon && this.position === 'left' && <ifx-icon icon={this.icon}></ifx-icon>}
   <slot></slot>
   {this.icon && this.position === 'right' && <ifx-icon icon={this.icon}></ifx-icon>}
</button>
```

Relevant button css:

```
.btn {
  display: inline-flex; 
  align-items: center;
  min-width: 80px;
  min-height: 40px;
  padding: 0px 16px;
  gap: 8px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  flex-direction: row;
  font-weight: 600;
  border-radius: 1px;
  line-height: 24px;
  outline: none;
  font-family: tokens.$font-family-body;
  text-decoration: none;
  user-select: none;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  font-size: 1rem;
  transition: color .15s ease-in-out, background-color .15s ease-in-out, border-color .15s ease-in-out, box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;
}
```

Icon component:

```
 <Host>
    {this.constructIcon()}
 </Host>
```

Icon component CSS:

```
ifx-icon { 
  display: inline-flex;
}
```

HTML:
my button
my button

Result:
[image: Buttons]

If both icons are bell-16, both buttons are perfectly alined.
If I removed the inline-flex from the icon component, I get this:
[image: No flex]

..obviously because the icon is not aligned in the center inside the icon component, and has larger line-height than the text.
[image: buttons2]

Question: What pushes the left button down when the right one has a larger icon? Is it the line-height of the icon svg? If so, can it be prevented?

Comment: Please add an [Minimal minimal-reproducible-example StackOverflow Snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your post. It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. See [How to add a StackOverflow snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers)

Comment: I can't. As I said, this is Stencil.js Web Component.

Comment: Your `<button>` does not have `class="btn"`. Is that part of your problem or did you post incomplete code? Please fix it to keep us all from having to guess at what you are doing. This is a CSS layout problem - not related to Stencil except for having to use Stencil to create/apply the CSS layout. Look into flexbox - especially `align-items` - see https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/.

Comment: You can use [webcomponents.dev](https://webcomponents.dev/) which supports Stencil.